# Forgot Password Icon? How's this?

Tags: icons, password

I've been using just a little speech bubble with a question mark in the middle to signify a lost password link, like this one:

[image]

For a redesign of the site, I've created a new one that I think better signifies it?

[image]

Does this better communicate to the user what the link actually is or should I just forget it and use the text link only?

This is how the login form now looks:

[image]

Comment: While I do think that you should stick to just text since the less complex a login form the better, I feel that it should be noted that I do like the new icon much better than the last.

Comment: I don't see this as a Icon Suggestion question at all. It is asking if the second icon better communicates the message.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you don't want to put any strong focus on the forgot-password link. If someone's forgot the password, he will look for it.

The important point is to integrate the link in the user's workflow. Mostly he excepts the link near the Login button. For convenience reasons I would place it as a link right next to the button OR right below.

Another important thing is to keep the link short. This whole "click here to" is from another decade. With "Forgot password?" the user knows exactly that that's the link he needs. If you style the link clearly as a link, nothing can goes wrong.

[image]

Comment: See how I have the login form designed?

Comment: I just updated my answer (last paragraph)

Comment: I also suggest using a generic catch all link with limited text.  `Need help?`, `Forgot password?`, `Can't access your account?`  --  http://www.ayso20.org/sites/default/files/images/Google%20Login%20Screen_0.preview.png

Comment: @DaveAlger, we will probably change it to `Can't access your account?` after we determine a process to enable them to change their email.

Comment: your icon is much nicer than the previous one